# Goaccess custom nginx log format

Tags: logging, nginx, goaccess

I need some help with parsing my log, tried several times and can't get it to be parsed.

Here is its format from the config we use:

```
log_format upstream_time_log '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                          '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                          '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time $upstream_response_time $upstream_response_length';
```

and a sample string:

`ourhost.com 91.234.31.36 - - [19/Sep/2016:07:46:51 +0000] "GET /url/goes/here/ HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" 0.000 - -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
log-format %v %h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" %T %^
date-format %d/%b/%Y
time-format %T
```

Answer (score 4):

This bash script [nginx2goaccess](https://github.com/stockrt/nginx2goaccess) can convert the format from nginx to goaccess

Example this command:

```
./nginx2goaccess.sh '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
```

Produce:

```
time-format %T
date-format %d/%b/%Y
log_format %h - %^ [%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```